# erro ao tentar subir aplicação usando Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, ejb

estou aprendendo EJB, e recebi um projeto que usa EJB, só que resolvi usar o Wildfly. quando subo aplicação apresenta um erro.

```
     service org.wildfly.request-controller.control-point."livraria.war".undertow (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./livraria.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990

20:15:21,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found livraria.war in deployment direc
```

Ao tentar adiconar o meu servidor estou com esse aviso, o que faço a partir dai estou com esse erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990  Verifica se não existe um processo do wildfly sendo executada ou se a porta está em uso por outra aplicação

Comment: hum.... o que você sugeria para que possa resolver esse problema.

Comment: reinicia o computador, se persistir verifica se tem algum outro aplicativo usando a porta 9990

Comment: ao rodar, ficou do mesmo jeito. Vejo que quando coloco localhost:8080 abre a página do wildfly

Comment: A porta 9990 do wildfly é para administração. Você precisa verificar se existe outro aplicativo que está usando a porta.

Comment: coloquei um print ai, eu até deletei meu container que era o tomcat e coloquei apenas esse Wildfly mais nada.